# The SDK windows jungle

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sdk

I'm kind of lost with all these SDK windows versions.

For instance, I installed vs2013 on windows8.1, and I (also) need to link my apps against vs2008 runtime (**platform toolset**).

Should I install the whole VS2008 too or just the API. In the last case, what SDK do I have to install ?

Comment: I don't understand the part about VS2008. Do you need to link against the runtime that ships with VS2008 or do you need to use the compilers that come with VS2008 (or both)?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear. I modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about two very distinct things.  The Windows SDK only covers the declarations and libraries that you need to make winapi calls.  SDK v8.1 is suitable to target any modern Windows version since Vista, you select the Windows version you want to target by setting the _WIN32_WINNT macro.  Note that XP requires an older SDK version, v7.1 is the last one that's still suitable and selected by setting the Platform Toolset to v120_xp.

The runtime libraries are a pure implementation detail of Visual Studio C/C++ projects and completely unrelated to the SDK.  When you build such a program on VS2013 with the /MD compile option then it will have a dependency on msvcr120.dll, possibly msvcp120.dll and others.  These DLLs implement the C runtime library and the C++ standard classes.  And possibly MFC, ATL, OpenMP and AMP if you use those libraries.

If you still have a dependency on the VS2008 version of those libraries then you are liable to have a Really Big problem.  You can obtain the release versions of those DLLs from the redist installer you can download from Microsoft.  Having a dependency on the debug version requires having VS2008 installed on your machine.  But having trouble linking the program and misery at runtime is highly indicated, the runtime libraries changed a great deal between VS2008 and VS2013 thanks to the new C++11 language standard.  Having more than one CRT in a program is in general liable to cause lots of trouble.

You need to strongly pursue getting the library that still has the VS2008 dependency rebuilt.  Contact the owner of the library if necessary to get an update.